# JQuery ASP.NET MVC drag and drop shopping cart doesnt retain cart items when navigating to different category

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I am very new to ASP.NET MVC and JQuery, I have built a e-commerce website in ASP.NET MVC, JQuery & C#. I used the Drag & Drop model from  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301620/Drag-Drop-Shopping-Cart-Using-Asp-net-MVC-and-JQuery which is great. I have modified the JQuery to meet all of my needs in regards to data retrieval, posting back data etc.

The problem I am having is I have different product categories that use my products.cshtml (view) so when a user wants to add more items to the current cart and the navigate to a new category all the existing items in the cart are removed when the postback occurs. My question is how do I keeps the current items in the cart when navigating to a different category.

Comment: What is the question ? Or are you just expecting, that people will write free code for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save changes of you cart somewhere. That somewhere may be cookie, database, session, etc. I would recommend to save that to database. To save that to database there may be various approaches, but you'll need for sure call action on server side, as long as you're using jQuery and Drag&Drop, probably that would be ajax call to MVC Action, that would save cart contents.

If you'll look at the comments of an article you've mentioned, I think there's solution for saving cart contents to database.

Comment: Thank you Giedrius but I figured out what I was doing wrong and you are right about storing data in Db which is what I was already doing.